# Dynamic nginx proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, tcp, proxy, forward

I would like to have every single IP request be redirect to a different on-demand created hostname. For example IP `11.22.33.44` should be redirected to the host which has DNS entry of `box-11-22-33-44`. (There is already a manager taking care of creating such DNS/box, you can assume that the link does exist).

The `nginx` proxy will be listening on multiple TCP ports to redirect to. However, to keep it simple, let's use port `80` as an example. I did try the following `stream` configuration which is running in a k8s pod:

```
stream {
 
    log_format  basic   'From $remote_addr to server-$remote_addr'
    ' Proxy: "$upstream_addr"'
    ;
    access_log      /var/log/nginx/stream.log  basic buffer=1k flush=1s;

    map $remote_addr $backend_svr {
      ~(.*)\.(.*)\.(.*)\.(.*)    box-$1-$2-$3-$4:80;
    }

    server {
      # resolver 10.96.0.10 ; # <--- DOES HOLD AND DOES NOT WORK
      listen 80;
      proxy_pass $backend_svr;
      proxy_protocol on;
   }
}
```

However, the previous configuration does not work and does either timeout on the DNS resolution or fails to resolve the `box-$1-$2-$3-$4:80` at all.

Is there anyway to have `nginx` work for my scenario where I need dynamic proxy forwarding?